# In React.js, how are nested components’ lifecycle methods called?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I’m just getting started in React (technically React native), and I’m trying to get the updated information from input components (like TextInput) back to the containing component, so that (1) the data is displayed correctly and (2) so the data can be written back to the underlying data store.

I’ve got the data being sent back, but it isn’t working like I expect ... I think because I’m using the wrong lifecycle phase method, or I’m not doing something that I need to do (like a force update).

So my question is this: how do nested components’ lifecycle methods get called? In this example:

```
<CompA>
    <CompB />
</CompA>
```

Would it be ...

```
CompB.render()
CompB.componentDidUpdate()
CompA.render()
CompA.componentDidUpdate()
```

... or ...

```
CompB.render()
CompA.render()
CompB.componentDidUpdate()
CompA.componentDidUpdate()
```

Or something else?